# Is there a way to do local import for arguments in python decorators and types in annotations?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am writing a python package with many functions, where I set local imports inside them to avoid a missing package error (so that my other functions can still work even if I do not have a certain package installed).

However, I have written a decorator to wrap some of my functions, but I cannot do local import if the argument in the decorator requires certain package. A similar local import problem occurs when I need to import a certain type from another package in the annotation of the function argument.

```py
def do_fancy_stuff(arg):
    def wrapped_func(func):
        def inner_func():
            print(f"Using {arg} on the target function!")
            # Some other statements to define the inner function, for simplicity here I just run func()
            func()
        return inner_func
    return wrapped_func

@do_fancy_stuff("A")
def some_func1():
    import numpy
    pass

@do_fancy_stuff("B")
def some_func2():
    pass

# How can I avoid an import statement here and put it in the decorator?
# import numpy
@do_fancy_stuff(numpy.inf) # error here
def some_func3():
    pass

# Similarly I need to import numpy outside the function if I want to do the annotation...
# import numpy
def other_func1(input_array : numpy.ndarray): # Error
    pass
```

I have an idea to use try-except for all the imports outside the function. But that will ruin my original idea that all dependencies of a function should be defined locally within that function.

Another idea is to use `exec` or to write a small function to wrap it, but it seems to make the codes much less readable:

```py
def _get_numpy_inf():
    import numpy
    return numpy.inf
```

Is there any better way to do the local import directly within the decorator statement and annotation, something like?

```
@do_fancy_stuff(import numpy; numpy.inf) 
(import numpy; @do_fancy_stuff(numpy.inf) )
def other_func1(input_array : import numpy; numpy.ndarray):
# Just some imaginations, it doesn't work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will attempt to provide an answer to your question, but before I do, please hear me out:

## Programmers should never have to write code which assumes dependencies may be missing

If any user of your project installs the dependencies of the project using a requirements file, then the dependencies should all be available, allowing all files and functions to run as intended.

Importing modules at the top of a file is good programming practice, and it makes managing the dependencies of a file simple and straightforward, while also allowing usage of those modules in places outside of the functions.

### Virtual environment

In order to successfully manage dependencies of a project, it is common to use a virtual environment, and a requirements file for any python project. This kind of practice is widely used in languages other than python as well.

To create a virtual environment in a folder named `venv`, use this command in your shell: `python -m venv venv`

To activate that environment, use this command: `source venv/bin/activate`

### Installing dependencies

To then install all of your project's dependencies, you can call `pip install -r requirements.txt`. You can also do this step without using a virtual environment. If you choose to do it that way, it will install the dependencies in your global python modules. This may not be desired at all times, hence the existence of virtual environments.

A requirements file is really simple. It just lists your dependencies on individual lines. It looks like the following:

```
numpy
matplotlib
another_dependency
```

And so on...

## Answering Your Question

Even though I really do not recommend going with the import structure that you currently have, I will suggest the following solution:

Use another function to create a scope around the dependent value. Return the decorated function from this new function.

```
# How can I avoid an import statement here and put it in the decorator?
def some_func3():
    import numpy
    @do_fancy_stuff(numpy.inf) # error here
    def f():
        pass
    return f

# Similarly I need to import numpy outside the function if I want to do the annotation...
def other_func1():
    import numpy
    def f(input_array : numpy.ndarray): # Error
        pass
    return f
```

Call the functions:

```
some_func3()()
other_func1()(numpy.ones(20))
```

Looking at a solution like this should make it clear that the syntax for using these functions will become awkward and confusing to read. Following the guide above the answer should make things a lot easier for you going forward :)

Comment: Helpful, but the tone could be off-putting, especially for someone new to software development. May I suggest smoothing over with a gentler tone? _(Your answer is very helpful. I want it to reach its intended audience with ease.)_

Comment: I agree, I'll try some edits for a lighter tone :D

Comment: @YaakovBressler I mean, this answer seems to be bending over backwards to not be off-putting. More than I would consider good. What would you suggest, specifically, to change the tone?

Comment: Maybe it was how I read it --> with the bold headers and such. @juanpa.arrivillaga --> on a second read, I agree, it is respectful.

Comment: I find that changing sentences to suggest good things, rather than attacking bad things makes it feel a lot less like talking-down, so I went with several of those changes.

Comment: Looks much better. Excellent change from `you should never...` to --> `programmers should never`...

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic answer! My package is designed to accept a data type to do the plotting, but the data is stored in many different file formats. Sadly each file format requires a specific package to read it. I try to avoid forcing the users to install all packages (because they may only need to plot the data with one file format). Is it a better practice to make all imports on top and set a bool like HAS_FORMAT_A_SUPPORT to indicate whether the user can use a certain function?

Comment: If the number of modules required is small (something like 3 or 4), then it may not be too much of an issue to have them install all of them, even if they only need some of them. Perhaps what you could do is separate the different format types into different files, so that they can import at the top, but only actually import those files if that format is being used. Try ideas like these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793748/python-doing-conditional-imports-the-right-way or others, and take advantage of similarly named functions in different files. Might do what you need :)