# Route modules import

Tags: python, module

I want to route a module import in python dynamically. See the example

```
src
├── main.py
├── module1
│   └── lib.py
└── module2
    └── lib.py
```

in main.py

```
import src.module.lib

(... use the module...)
```

Imagine I have an env var **$MODULE**, if $MODULE=1, it will import **module1** if $MODULE=2 it will import **module2**.

**I cannot change main.py code!**

I believe adding a src/__init__.py is the way to go. What to do from here?

EDIT:

I bit more context to give more clarity on what's the real problem. `main.py` is actually a huge code base that should remain unchanged also because it would be counter-productive to add conditional importing to all files in the codebase and maintain it.

Therefore, I would like to be able to configure (by an environment variable, by file, by whatever) the behavior of module importing within `src` without changing the rest of the Python files. I assumed I could do this routing in `src/__init__.py`.

Comment: `if MODULE == 1: import module1 as module; elif MODULE == 2: import module2 as module` ?

Comment: Or is your question how you can access environment variables?

Comment: @mkrieger1 thanks for your comment. Where does this code goes? If you are suggesting to change main.py code, please take a look again on the question. I cannot change main.py.

Comment: Yes, don't change `main.py`. Put this somewhere which can be imported from `main.py` as `module`.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your problem is also not how to write an `if` statement with an `import` inside, but how to structure the files?

Comment: One part of your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793748/python-doing-conditional-imports-the-right-way, anyway. The other parts are how to access environment variables and how to structure the files. It would be good if you showed what specifically went wrong with your attempt so that a focused answer can be written.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks again. Added more context to the question, I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this :

```
import os

module_choice = os.environ.get("MODULE")

if module_choice == "1":
    from .module1 import lib
elif module_choice == "2":
    from .module2 import lib
else:
    raise ImportError("Invalid MODULE value. Set MODULE=1 or MODULE=2.")
```

Comment: Thank you. Where does this code goes? The questions states I cannot change `main.py` code.

Comment: you can just put this code in main.py on the top and you have to create a env key "module" and it will load module with respect to that

Comment: "you can just put this code in main.py" this is exactly the opposite of what the question is asking for.

Comment: you have to put something in main.py either this code or you can create a modules files where you put this code and call it from main.py